# Should I have multiple repositories?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Does having multiple repositories increase resource usage?

I have followed this tutorial for adding a repository service that holds a database context: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api

In the tutorial the repository is for managing a Todo item.  In my own app I have several different types of items and activities that I need a context for.  Should I create an individual repository for each?  For instance one repository for enquiries, another for user usage metrics?  Is there any overhead or penalty for doing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Should I create an individual repository for each? For instance one repository for enquiries, another for user usage metrics? Is there any overhead or penalty for doing this?

Yes.  No.

Generally you want to have **one repository per entity type** because each entity type is going to more than likely require **operations specific to its type beyond the cliche CRUD operations**.  The aim of the repo is to **eliminate duplicate data query logic** that would otherwise be littered about your application.

e.g.

```
interface IRepo { CRUD }

protected abstract class RepoBase<T> : IRepo 
{
   // CRUD implementation
}

public class PatientRepo : RepoBase<Patient>
{ 
    List<IPatient> GetAllTerminallyIllPatients();
}

public class MusicRepo : RepoBase<Music>
{
    List<ISong> GetAllSongsByArtist (string artist);
}
```

Note how each repo in my feeble example is customised to the entity type.   If you didn't do this your single repo would quickly

- become hard to find that method you're after
- unmanageble with the potential for 100s of methods
- lead to increased probability of source control conflict due to all code being in one file

You might want to consider splitting your repos into repos **and** *unit of work* classes because:

> Repositories should not have semantics of your database.  It should
>   be like a collection of objects in memory and should not methods like
>   update and save. - [Mosh](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rtXpYpZdOzM)

You can learn more from the tutorial in the link below.

> Does having multiple repositories increase resource usage?

Generally no, because for any given operation, **all of your interested repos** would be **attached** to the **same database context instance**.  It is the context that is expensive, not the repo.

### Tell me more

- [Repository Pattern with C# and Entity Framework, Done Right](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rtXpYpZdOzM)

Comment: Thanks.  That was a really helpful answer.

Comment: No worries good sir.  Mosh's video gave me some great tips too :)

Comment: This is a great answer. A couple more references folks may find helpful: Generic repository implementation: http://deviq.com/repository-pattern/ and implementing caching with the CachedRepository pattern: http://ardalis.com/introducing-the-cachedrepository-pattern

Comment: @ssmith Thanks good buddy for you kind words and for the fine links.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the link provided The Repository pattern can be used to abstract the data access into an interface, in the example: `ITodoRepository`.

Why do you abstract data access? This way you could easily switch data-access layer by implementing a different class of `ITodoRepository` Say if you want to test your logic with unit tests, or if the possibility exists you wont be using entity framework anymore in the future.

If this is not the case and you are building a small project with no such future additions (unit tests/switch data-access layer) Making use of the Repository pattern is only extra work without any benefits.

So you should decide if the extra work of making the repository pattern outweighs the benefits for your project.